# callback function not showing as defined

Tags: json, google-maps-api-3

http://wrestore.iupui.edu/model/mapScriptTry.html (doesnt work here)
http://wrestore.iupui.edu/fusion/multipleMarkersJonOnClick.html (works here)

```
url.push('&callback=drawWet1')
```

in an attempt to call the callback drawWet1 in the line above, I was getting an error that it was undefined. My question was why is this occurring. It is clearly a function. It was answered below by stating that I needed to make the function a variable and call it that way. So

```
function drawWet1(){ 
}
```

becomes

```
drawWet1=function(data){
}
```

I could then access that inside my function making the callback.

So geocodezip, I have redone your script and gotten it to work on other pages but am now getting an error that the callback function is not defined. I am confused. url.push('&callback=drawWet1'); when that runs it tells me that drawWet1 is not defined yet it is! I don't see any difference in calling between the two pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions are not defined in global scope, currently they are visible only inside initialize() (That's where they are currently placed).

Instead of defining the functions like this:

```
function drawWet1(data){//...
```

do it like that:

```
drawWet1=function(data){//....
```

...or define the functions outside  of initalize()

Comment: Yes! Thanks Dr. Molle. Learning by doing.....!

Answer (score 1):

All your functions are local to the initialize function, except toggleLayers.  Move them to the global scope (outside of any other function).